# Flutter Firebase fetch a nested data

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So my app suggest a list of tourist places and the data is fetched from firebase.
So, I have added a search bar where the user can search that tourist place and it will be shown.
Now the problem is that it is not showing the searched place in the listView.

Here is the firebase ScreenShot:

**Example -> I want to search and show  "India Gate" in the ListView , so how should I do it.**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3G5W.png)

**Here is my Code**

Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, left: 0, right: 0),

```
            child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('States')
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {

                  var docs = snapshot.data.docs[widget.stateIndex];
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    /// MediaQuery.removePadding is used to remove the blank space which appears on the top of ListView.
                    return MediaQuery.removePadding(
                      context: context,
                      removeTop: true,

                      /// Here ClipRRect is wrapped on ListView to make the Scrolling border rounded.
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(45),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(45)),
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            print(
                                "Value: ${widget.stateIndex} + ${docs['places'].length}");
                            print(docs.data());
                            print("Hello-----------------");
                            print(docs['places'][index]["location"]);
                            return Container(
                              height: deviceSize.height * .225,
                              child: Card(
                                elevation: 10,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                        Radius.circular(20))),
                                child: Stack(
                                  children: [
                                    /// Background Place Image.
                                    ClipRRect(
                                        child: Image.network(
                                          docs['places'][index]["img"],
                                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                          width: deviceSize.width,
                                        ),
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                                    /// Text Widget.
                                    Positioned(
                                      bottom: 4,
                                      left: 10,
                                      child:  Container(
                                        height: 25,
                                        width: 185,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                          color: SecondPrimaryColor,
                                        ),
                                        child: Row(
                                                children: [
                                                  Image.asset(
                                                      "assets/icon.png",
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      height: 18,
                                                      filterQuality:
                                                          FilterQuality.high),
                                                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                                                  AutoSizeText(
                                                    docs['places'][index]["venue"],
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                        color: Colors.white,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                                    maxFontSize: 22,
                                                    minFontSize: 14,
                                                  ),
                                                ],

                                            ),
                                      )),

                                    // Positioned(
                                    //   right: 30,
                                    //     bottom: 6,
                                    //     child: Container(
                                    //       height: 18,
                                    //       width: 50,
                                    //
                                    //       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    //         borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                    //         color: PrimaryColor,
                                    //       ),
                                    //       child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward,color: SecondPrimaryColor,size: 18),
                                    //     ))
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          itemCount: docs['places'].length,
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    return Text("No Data");
                  }
                }),
          ),
```

Comment: What is the output of `docs['places']`, for example if you run `print(docs['places'])`? If you do `docs.length` what do you get? If your `ListView.builder` is not displaying anything, you could first basically check that you actually have data to show.

Comment: @James The output of docs['places'] is the map of all the items inside it, you can see the database in the image link  i have added .                
and if I print docs.length it gives --------> Class '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot' has no instance getter 'length'.
Receiver: Instance of '_JsonQueryDocumentSnapshot'
Tried calling: length

Comment: @Abishek, what I meant when I asked what the output of `docs['places']` was are you actually successfully pulling in the data from Firestore? I just want to make sure that your app actually has the data to display, before thinking of anything else. In the past, it happened to me that the ListView didn't display anything, but there were no errors, and it turned out there were just no suggestions to display.

Comment: `docs` is a single document and so `docs.length` will throw an error. First define `var data = docs.data();` on top the `mediaQuery.removePadding`. Everywhere after this line `print("Hello-----------------");`, replace docs with data.

Answer (score 0):

Use docs.data() to convert to `Map<String, dynamic>` and display your data instead of docs['places'];

Something like this:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>( // changes made
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('States').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    // changes made
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc =
          snapshot.data.docs[widget.stateIndex];
      Map<String, dynamic> data = doc.data(); // changes made

      /// MediaQuery.removePadding is used to remove the blank space which appears on the top of ListView.
      return MediaQuery.removePadding(
        context: context,
        removeTop: true,
        /// Here ClipRRect is wrapped on ListView to make the Scrolling border rounded.
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
            topLeft: Radius.circular(45),
            topRight: Radius.circular(45),
          ),
          child: ListView.builder(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              print(data);
              print(
                  "Value: ${widget.stateIndex} + ${data['places'].length}");
              print('Hello-----------------');
              // changes made
              print(data['places'][index]['location']);
              return Container(
                height: deviceSize.height * .225,
                child: Card(
                  elevation: 10,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  ),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      /// Background Place Image.
                      ClipRRect(
                        child: Image.network(
                          data['places'][index]['img'],
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          width: deviceSize.width,
                        ),
                        borderRadius:
                            const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                      ),
                      /// Text Widget.
                      Positioned(
                        bottom: 4,
                        left: 10,
                        child: Container(
                          height: 25,
                          width: 185,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                              Radius.circular(10),
                            ),
                            color: SecondPrimaryColor,
                          ),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Image.asset(
                                'assets/icon.png',
                                color: Colors.white,
                                height: 18,
                                filterQuality: FilterQuality.high,
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 10),
                              AutoSizeText(
                                data['places'][index]['venue'],
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                ),
                                maxFontSize: 22,
                                minFontSize: 14,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            itemCount: data['places'].length,
          ),
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return const Text('No Data');
    }
  },
);
```